# How to create a new tab based on a text length?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-sliding

I'm implementing a fragment which is based in a `ViewPager` for sliding slides ([see here](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)).

So, I would like to know if it's possible to get a new sliding tab dynamically, based on a text length (which is displayed in a `TextView` inside of `ViewPager`) I want to display inside that `ViewPager` (to get a similar book view).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Go back to that link you posted about `ViewPager` and re-read it focusing on `PagerAdapter`.  The concept is similar to the list adapter.  So for example, you create a `PagerAdapter` that will take your content (in a constructor, for example), and determine how the content is broken up into pages.  Say you pass in some content and your `PagerAdapter` determines there are 17 pages.  Your override for `PagerAdapter.getCount()` would return 17.  Then in `instantiateItem()` (or maybe `getItem()`, if you're using `FragmentPagerAdapter`), you would create the view that is to be displayed at page `position`, which is a parameter.

**Fair Warning!** It sounds like you want to page some text horizontally like pages in a book.  You should know that `TextView` won't be able to do things like, "well I'm this size, so I can display this much text".  You will need to use things like `android.text.StaticLayout` to figure out stuff like that.  Do-it-yourself text layout is advanced Android programming, so brace yourself.